# Woocommerce redirection product_name -> product_cat/product_name

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

First, the product url was /product_name.
But the boss wished to change it to product_cat/product_name. Where product_cat is the primary category.
So the plugin Premmerce has been installed and the new url are correct.
But, Google has already indexed product pages with the previous url. Thus, i need to redirect all old url to new.
For example http://chaiseguy.kamilane.odns.fr/abstrait-2/ to http://chaiseguy.kamilane.odns.fr/t-shirts/abstrait-2/
The plugin Redirection was already installed so I tried with a new redirection : /%product_name% to /%product_cat%/%product_name%
But it doesn't work.

So I tried with .htaccess with adding :
Redirect 301 https://chaiseguy.kamilane.odns.fr/%product_name% https://chaiseguy.kamilane.odns.fr/%product_cat%/%product_name%
It doesn't work :-(

How can I do ???

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `template_redirect` action. Check if current request is a single product.
@see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    //= bail early
    if( !is_404() ) return;

    //= get product name from url
    $product_name = get_query_var( 'pagename' );

    //= bail
    if( empty( $product_name ) ) return;

    //= lookup product by name
    $product = get_page_by_path( $product_name, OBJECT, 'product' );

    //= bail
    if( is_null( $product ) ) return;

    //= redirect
    wp_redirect( get_the_permalink( $product->ID ) );
    exit;

} );
```

Note #1 in addition you might want to check if query_var "product_cat" is empty. Otherwise you might end up with an infinite loop.

Note #2 try to add some logic ( add it if it doesn't exist, otherwise skip logic ) to pass the redirect to the Redirection plugin. Idea above will run on every request. If it's just a redirect sitting in the Redirection plugin, it will be faster.

Hope this sets you on the right track.
Sorry I don't have the exact solution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but, I'm sorry, it doesn't work. I copied your code in functions.php and the page displays wrong. Like the template cannot to be load. Is it possible I have to use the wp_redirect function at the place of template_redirect ?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code in a working example IF the old URLs result in a 404. Otherwise you will need to play with the available query_vars to get the $product_name. Based on that you can re-use the code above.